# python AttributeError not finding a class within a module I am importing

Tags: python, class, module, package, attributeerror

I have a package containing a module called rigfuncs3.py

```
SDNpackage/
    __init__.py
    rigfuncs3.py
```

Code:

```
class rig():

    def __init__(self, rigNumber, leftNozPlate, rightNozPlate, bottomNozPlate, row1_centre_focus):

        self.rigNumber = rigNumber
        self.leftNozPlate = leftNozPlate
        self.rightNozPlate = rightNozPlate
        self.bottomNozPlate = bottomNozPlate
        self.row1_centre_focus = row1_centre_focus

    def getRigName(self):
        return self.rigNumber
```

A script called play_04.py imports the module rigfuncs from the package. 
Code:

```
from SDNpack2 import rigfuncs3

instantiation = rigfuncs3.rig(1,1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0)
print(dir(instantiation))

rig_num = instantiation.getRigName()
```

When run play_04 I get the error:

AttributeError: 'rig' object has no attribute 'getRigName'

I have no idea why, any ideas?

Comment: I'm failing to find a problem with your provided code. Are you sure that the class `rig` is defined in `rigfuncs.py`? Also can you please update your code so that _only_ the code needed to replicate the problem is provided? Could you also provide a folder-structure for your package? If you're using windows, move into the "root" directory of your package and issue the command `tree /f` and give us that output as well.

Comment: The code shown is the total code for both files, I fixed it by adding another import in play_02 from rigfuncs import rig. which fixes that issue but moves me on to another problem.

Comment: The only way I could see that your problem is occurring is if you're polluting the namespace inside of the package (which seems likely because you've reused `rig` multiple times). Please read through [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your code accordingly so that we can help you find the root cause.

Comment: @HampusLarsson thank you I shall read this.

Comment: @HampusLarsson hi, I have read the doc and totally changed the question to relflect the simplifiedcode and structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still cannot replicate the problem you're having.

I've tried to copy your stated folder-structure like this:

```
C:.
│   play_04.py
│
└───SDNpack2
        rigfuncs3.py
        __init__.py     <--- empty file
```

**rigfuncs3.py:**

```
class rig():
    def __init__(self, rigNumber, leftNozPlate, rightNozPlate, bottomNozPlate, row1_centre_focus):
        self.rigNumber = rigNumber
        self.leftNozPlate = leftNozPlate
        self.rightNozPlate = rightNozPlate
        self.bottomNozPlate = bottomNozPlate
        self.row1_centre_focus = row1_centre_focus

    def getRigName(self):
        return self.rigNumber
```

**play_04.py:**

```
from SDNpack2 import rigfuncs3

instantiation = rigfuncs3.rig(1, 1000.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0)
print(instantiation)
print(instantiation.__dict__)

rig_num = instantiation.getRigName()
print(rig_num)
```

I change your call of `dir(instantiation)` into `instantiation.__dict__` to just show the attributes of the object, not all built-in variables.

Output:

```
<SDNpack2.rigfuncs3.rig object at 0x02B1E628>
{'rigNumber': 1, 'leftNozPlate': 1000.0, 'rightNozPlate': 2000.0, 'bottomNozPlate': 3000.0, 'row1_centre_focus': 4000.0}
1
```

The only way I can replicate the problem in of itself is if I either change the indentation of `getRigName` or if I remove it all together from the class.

Your code works the way you have coded it, I see no actual problem here.

Comment: I made a new package with just __init__.py and rigfuncs3.py and it works too. I’ve accepted your answer because you advised in a comment that it may be the package structure. I didn’t know instantiation.__dict__ gave the attributes - I have no idea what all the private methods do, thank you Hampus your help has helped me learn a lot in the last few days.

Comment: @Windy71 When you call `dir` on an object, you're showing all the "stuff" that is inside of that object. Some of those are sometimes called "magic methods" which change how the object behaves. You can read more about them [here](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/). Two of the best ones to try to start implementing of those are `__repr__` and `__str__` which handles how your class handles calls from `repr()` and `str()` respectively. If `__str__` is not defined, it then automatically falls back to call `__repr__`.